# How use axios in web worker with vue?

Tags: vue.js, axios, web-worker

I've try use axios request in web worker by [vue plugin](https://github.com/israelss/vue-worker)

My code looks like this:

```js
//worker.js

import axios from 'axios';

export default function getApiData(args) {
  axios.get('/api/test').then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

And main file with Vue

```js
//main.js

import getApiData from './worker.js';

Vue.use(VueWorker);

window.vueApp = new Vue({
  //...
  created: function() {
    this.updateWorker = this.$worker.create([
      {
        message: 'getApiData ',
        func: getApiData 
      }
    ]);
    
    this.testWorker.postMessage('getApiData ', [this.args])
        .then(result => {
          console.log(result);
        })
  },
  //...
}
```

And I got this error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default is
> not defined

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: As i figured out the problem is in webpack which builds files incorrectly

Comment: I had the same problem and I managed to solve using the fetch directly

Comment: @MelNik - did you resolve that? I've also like @GustavoAdolfo resorted to `fetch`

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela not really, instead of this plugin I used the native capabilities of web workers

Comment: is there any fix for this with respect to webpack? I am experiencing this with any usage of promises, either in my code or external libraries, so this seems like a big problem. If you figured it out, you should post the solution

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and solved it by going back to the basics - using plain old XMLRequest (see below).

You can't use axios inside the worker because the blob that's created behind the scenes to load the `worker.js` runs in a different context than your `main.js`. In order for axios to work, you would have to setup a new webpack bundler to just bundle the worker by itself. I didn't want to do that - it makes the project structure unnecessary complex.

Here is a simple solution (works with json and non-json response).

```js
// worker.js

export default () => {
  self.addEventListener('message', e => {
    if (!e) return;

    // wrap in try/catch if you want to support IE11 and older browsers
    // that don't support Promises. The implementation below doesn't work
    // even when polyfills are loaded in the main project because
    // the worker runs in a different context, ie no webpack bundles here.
    try {
      const fetchData = (url, isJSON = true) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          function reqListener() {
            if (this.status !== 200) {
              return reject();
            }
            const response = isJSON
              ? JSON.parse(this.responseText)
              : this.responseText;
            resolve(response);
          }
          const oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
          oReq.addEventListener('load', reqListener);
          oReq.open('GET', url);
          oReq.send();
        });
      };

      const baseUrl = 'https://static.newsfilter.io/';
      const { articleId } = e.data;


      const jsonUrl = baseUrl + articleId + '.json';
      const htmlUrl = baseUrl + articleId + '.html';

      // My use case requires 2 requests in parallel. 
      const tasks = [fetchData(jsonUrl), fetchData(htmlUrl, false)];

      Promise.all(tasks)
        .then(data => {
          postMessage({ json: data[0], html: data[1] });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          postMessage({ isError: true, error });
        });
    } catch (error) {
      postMessage({ isError: true });
    }
  });
};
```